# How to see console.logs of a running nodeJs application on ubuntu 18 EC2 instance?

Tags: reactjs, express, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am new to the node world. I created a node js rest API. When I run npm start in my local machine or in the terminal for the first time, I can see console.log() in my terminal. Now, I am running the same application on an AWS Ec2 instance with Ubuntu as os. I run npm start and serve my app on port 80. I do this via ssh and after running my server I close the ssh connection. But when I reconnect via ssh, I want to see those console.log() messages in my terminal for some purpose.

I completely understand that logging messages in the terminal is not a good idea and there can be so many alternatives. Just want to know how to access the same terminal window/result as we see when I start my application.

Comment: Hello Jasmohan!

When you deploy your app in a real server the logs are saved to a physical location. Where it depends on your system. What are you using to run your app? PM2? Forever?

Comment: @MattiaRasulo I am using nodmon to run my app.. thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Nodemon won't work well in a production server or in any instance where you need to have the app going by itself.

Nodemon is a dev tool to enable you to restart your server during development. In a "real" vps you need to place the process in the background or it will be automatically killed when the connection times out.

Check out this YT series for a correct deploy architecture in an NGINX server with the use of pm2 and NGINX on a Red Hat server, I've personally used it more than once:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQlWzK5tU-gDyxC1JTpyC2avvJlt3hrIh

Answer (score 2):

if you are using pm2, you can try "pm2 logs"

Comment: Try adding comments. Or please add more descriptive answer to the solution.